# Need to change the list element tag using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to change the list tag needs to come under the multiple list element values

My Input xml file is:

```
<ul>
<li>list</li>
<li>following list:</li>
<ul>
<li>pain</li>
<li>Changes</li>
</ul>
<li>exam</li>
</ul>
```

XSL I Have used as:

```
   <xsl:template match="ul">
      <ul>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </ul>
   </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="ul/li">
      <li outputclass="List_Bullet">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </li>
   </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="ul/ul/li">
      <li outputclass="List_Bullet_2">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </li>
   </xsl:template>
```

Output Im getting as:

```
<ul>
<li outputclass="List_Bullet">list</li>
<li outputclass="List_Bullet">following list:</li>
<ul>
<li outputclass="List_Bullet_2">pain</li>
<li outputclass="List_Bullet_2">Changes</li>
</ul>
<li outputclass="List_Bullet">exam</li>
</ul>
```

Expected output to be:

```
<ul>
<li outputclass="List_Bullet">list</li>
<li outputclass="List_Bullet">following list:
<ul>
<li outputclass="List_Bullet_2">pain</li>
<li outputclass="List_Bullet_2">Changes</li>
</ul></li>
<li outputclass="List_Bullet">exam</li>
</ul>
```

The first bullet list item needs to be close at the end of the second bullet list. Please suggest me the coding. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In This case you have to use mode attributes in template for wrapping.

You can try this:

```
<xsl:template match="ul">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul/li">
    <li outputclass="List_Bullet">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::ul]" mode="wrap"/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul/ul"/>

<xsl:template match="ul" mode="wrap">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="wrap"/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul/li" mode="wrap">
    <li outputclass="List_Bullet_2">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```